# Why does the survey notification bar keep showing me to take the survey even though I have completed it?

Tags: bug, survey

The Stack Overflow survey bar is being shown on the top page although I have completed it.

Each time I hope it is a different one, but it is always the same.

Therefore, if a user has completed the survey, please don't show them the survey bar.

[image]

Comment: Hey - at least you were invited to take it! Not all of us are so lucky :)

Comment: @Gimby, it was satisfaction survey, are you not satisfied with not being chosen for satisfaction survey?